# AJAX requests from jquery in android application to WCF Service always fails

Tags: c#, android, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have an application where I fetch a list of requests made by the user based on the idNo provided. The android application uses AJAX to make a request to a .NET WCF Service which in turn returns a IEnumerable of DTO for that request.
Following is the AJAX Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseURL + "RequestStatusList/"+idNo,
    cache : false,
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossdomain : true,
    success : function(data, tst, xhr) {
               //do something here
    },

    error: function (xhr, tst, err) {

        alert(' Please Try Again ' + xhr.status);
    }
    });
```

A similar piece of code works in another page in the application, where only the process in success is different, rest all is same.
Here every time the request fails and enters the error section and displays undefined/0 as error. No details about error, hence i cannot get what maybe the problem.
When I debug the server side code I get proper value in the parameter passed and a IEnumerable is formed and returned. What fails is the client side code after successful execution of server code.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: be sure u add jquery properlly.

Comment: other jquery scripts on the page are working fine. Hence we can say that I added jquery properly.